# Manipulate current URL to another temporary url

Tags: javascript

Let's assume that I am currently viewing content on the website "chat.openai.com." If I manually move my cursor to the URL box of the browser and delete the text that is currently there, "chat.openai.com," and then manually type "gourav.com," there are two possible outcomes. First, if I press Enter after typing "gourav.com," I will be redirected to "gourav.com." Second, if I click anywhere on the old webpage after typing writing mode in URL gets turn off and in URL section is showing that "gourav.com" is there but that's temporarily written there and behind it the actual page which is loaded that is "chat.openai.com"

I am trying to implement this by javascript but its giving me error

**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://www.gourav.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' and URL 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/check.html'.
at http://127.0.0.1:5500/check.html:8:21**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            // Change the URL to "http://www.gourav.com" when the page loads
            history.pushState(null, null, "http://www.gourav.com");
        });

        document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            if (event.target.tagName !== "A") {
                // Remove focus from the URL bar when the user clicks anywhere on the page (except on links)
                document.activeElement.blur();
            }
        });

        window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
            // Restore the original URL when the user clicks the back button or navigates away from the page
            history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put punctuation into your question so that it can be read without causing a headache.

Comment: done please check now

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to set another domain in url, while showing your site. If it was possible it would be easier for malicious websites to trick users and scam them.

Comment: But manually if we can do then why not from some script

Comment: if you are doing something manually - you probably want it. however scripts functionality is limited to prevent websites to harm someone. for example web app can not read any file on your computer, unless you manually select it in the file picker provided by the page.

Comment: Hey I found a proof site which is doing same or kind of same thing 

Here is link
https://shortify.live/J=m)=fM

Comment: they are doing full redirect. you see new url and new website after redirect

Comment: Oh I understand the navbar and URL bar was also fake

Comment: It's not a proof - it is a video with someone rambling over it. A proof would be a website that is actually doing what you describe. I can show you videos of a 2000 foot giant - doesn't make it proof that it is real.